# galaxy s6 messages app opens link in the messages browser instead of opening the app?

Tags: android, android-intent, samsung-mobile, deep-linking

I am developing an app where you get a text message with a link in it. 
When this said link is clicked normally the app opens (Huawei p9 lite, htc one m8) but when I try to test this on a galaxy s6/s7 the standard messaging app opens up the in-app browser.
Is there a workaround for this ?

Edit: example url: http://smsvalidation.example.com/en/123456789

Comment: any solution to this? im having the same issue

Comment: No, the link was used to validate an account. I just made it so that my app read the incoming text message in the background and validated like that.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this issue on s6 edge and s7 as well as the note series.
Here is what you could try:

- Use custom url scheme like myapp://xyz
- Redirect the user when the web page is loaded (not tested)
- Open an iframe with the url when the web page is loaded (not tested)
- Tinker with [android chrome intents](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents)